# iOS app file storage. YouTube, parse.com or local?

Tags: ios, database, video, youtube, parse-platform

I have an iOS app that uses a lot of pictures and videos. Currently, I use parse.com as backend and I store the pictures in parse.com database. Imagine I have 200 tasks, each task with two pictures and one video. Now, each user will have his own set of tasks, for example, user A may have 20 tasks, user B 40 and user C 50, all different tasks included on those 200.

Now, I'm worried about app performance, not so much server storage and other structure details...

I don't think including all pictures in the app bundle is a good idea, because user will use only about 40% of the pictures at a time, so it wouldn't be wise to include it all in the app. Instead, I have the pictures in database and when user needs, the app makes a request and gets it. Am I right about this? Is this the best performance?

Regarding the videos, should I store the videos in youTube.com or in my parse.com database? I think youTube is the best option because I can live stream the video whether in parse.com I will need to download the video first. Does that make sense?

If there are any other services or better way to handle pictures and videos in an iOS app, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding images - the best performance here is to store them remotely on a server and from what it seems, you're doing it right.

Storing videos on YouTube is not the best idea but definitely better then just storing them on your server - if you have the ability to upload multiple Youtube videos from lots of users and if Google API allows that - I'd go for this option.

In general I would store as little as possible on the device, apart from the image cache maybe. Nevertheless even the image cache sometimes grows to hundreds of MBs so you have to think about it as well.

Comment: For the videos, what would you suggest? Actually, users will not upload videos, they will have access to our institutional videos instead. Thanks

Comment: Loading videos from YouTube is a breeze in this case - it's a matter of an easy script and a `UIWebView` - the laziest and simplest (yet the most sane) implementation of all. Or you could even redirect them to Safari or the YouTube iOS app if you like.